# How to add a quotation mark to the beginning and end of each line in a string in php

Tags: php, regex

Im attempting to take a string that is in a partial comma separated setup.  I need to add a quotation mark or some other mark to the beginning and end of each line in the string.  The string in question has many lines like shown below.

IE

```
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
```

is to be turned into

```
"2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres"
```

I have tried many regex attempts but I have to admit that I am very poor in understanding regex.

Comment: This site may be useful to you...Rad Software Regular Expression Designer - http://www.radsoftware.com.au (tool to test regular expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abuse the fact the `.` does not match a newline.

```
$result = preg_replace('/(.+)/', '"$1"', $subject);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I would have never got that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the string is multiple lines long?

I'd be tempted to just create a new array containing each line, something like this:

```
<?php 
$string = '2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres'; // obviously use a string with multiple lines, but i'm just taking your example

$array = preg_split('/\n+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
  $array[$k]='"'.$v.'"';
}

print_r($array);
```

Or I supose you could always just use something like:

```
<?php
$newstring = '"'.str_replace("\n", "\"\n\"",$string).'"';
```

Although, the 2nd method might need a bit of refinement to take account of "\r" or "\r\n" as well.

Comment: ok this was what i was thinking but didn't know if there was a preg_replace (regex) that would solve the issue.  And yes, it is a multiple line string.

Comment: Have updated my answer after thinking about it a bit. The 2nd method might suffice for what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your answers are very useful. The answer below, i think, is better so i have marked it correct.  +1 to you for multiple solutions.  This will surely help others.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is:

```
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
```

And you only need double quotes at the begining and the end of each line you could use [strtr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$sLines = "2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres
2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres";

$arrTr = array();
$arrTr1 = array();
$arrTr[chr(13)] = '"'.chr(13).'"';
$arrTr1["\"\n"] = '"';

$sLines = strtr(strtr($sLines,$arrTr),$arrTr1);

$sLines = '"'.$sLines.'"';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sLines);
echo '</pre>';
```

But, if you have lines glued by the "\n" character you can do this:

```
$sLines = "2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres\n2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres\n2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres\n2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres\n2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres\n2011.11.12 20:06,Teac Ous,Solid Pyroxeres,46521,Pyroxeres";

$arrTr = array();
$arrTr1 = array();
$arrTr["\n"] = '"'."\n".'"';

$sLines = strtr($sLines,$arrTr);

$sLines = '"'.$sLines.'"';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sLines);
echo '</pre>';
```